# how to get the custom post id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to query wordpress for a particular custom post basis a meta_key and meta_value as follows:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'fs_park',
            //'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'osm_geometry',
                    'value'   => $osm_geometry,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );
        
        $my_query->query($args);
```

If I `print_r($my_query)` I can see the post id I want as follows:

```
WP_Query Object
(
    ...
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [0] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1074
                    ...
                 )
        )
)
```

Is there any wordpress function/method to access the ID but not in a loop?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ID on your query result without looping by directly accessing the ID of the 1st result of the array

```
$postID = $my_query->posts[0]->ID ?? null;
```

but if you want less overhead query, just use global `$wpdb` and `get_var` method to perform direct sql query in posts_meta table;

```
global $wpdb;

$postID = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = %s",
    'osm_geometry', $osm_geometry
));
```

this directly give you the post_ID the contains meta_key `osm_geometry` and the value you pass on `$osm_geometry`,

if there are more than 1 post containing the same value, you'll get the ID of the 1st result